# Get text from div class with jsoup and put it into a string

Tags: java, android, parsing, jsoup

I want to get text out of a div class, store it in a string and show the text in a TextView.
This is the website:

```
<div class="barTextBelow color_default">Datenvolumen mit voller Geschwindigkeit verbraucht
</div>
```

And this is my code:

```
@Override
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            title = doc.select("div[class=barTextBelow]").text();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Set title into TextView

        TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvused);
        txttitle.setText(title);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

But I get an empty TextView. Does anyone know why?

Thanks!

Comment: Not that it solves anything (or maybe it does), but wouldn't `div.barTextBelow` instead of `div[class=barTextBelow]` be better (simpler/shorter/easier to read)?

Comment: @Pshermo I tried that too, doesn't work :(

Comment: `div[class=barTextBelow]` will not work because value of `class` attribute is not only `barTextBelow` so `div.barTextBelow` is preferable. After correcting this problem test in some simple Java code (in `public static void main(String[] args)` method) if your *Jsoup* code is correct by printing value of `title` to console.

Comment: And how can I solve this? I just want the text from barTextBelow...

Comment: I am not Android developer but it seems that there are two main possible reasons why you don't see what you want: (1) either your code doesn't parse correctly page (2) you placed this code in wrong place of your application lifecycle.

Comment: To test first possibility you can create some simple class and add jsoup code to its main method and print results. To test if it is problem with lifecycle consider invoking this code (parsing html and presenting results in GUI) from place which you know that this code will for sure be invoked (like from handling pressing some button).

Comment: Suggest that you use http://try.jsoup.org/ to debug your selector, separately to your app. I.e. break this down into components and find the problem.

Comment: @Jonathan I tried it and it works fine for div.barTextBelow :(

Comment: So why the frowny face? Seems like you're on track. Now we know the selector works, but either your URL connect or the UI update doesn't work. Likely the former. Try setting a UserAgent on the request, maybe the server returns different content for mobile devices. Also try logging the HTML you get back after the connect, see that it's what you expected.

Comment: Yeah! It works with a new user agent! Thank you sooo much for this tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Div you have provided have two classes 'barTextBelow' and 'color_default' so I think it is working as expected.

You may also try:

```
doc.getElementsByClass("CLASS");
```

Comment: It should give me "Datenvolumen mit voller Geschwindigkeit verbraucht" in my string, but i get nothing...

Comment: Have you tried referencing your class names as it is : doc.getElementsByClass("barTextBelow color_default");